# SSIS - Execute Process Task failure - how to get the detailed error message

Tags: ssis, process, task, execute

I have a SSIS package that uses an Execute Process task to run a .bat script. For the purposes of this example, I made a very simple script that will fail. When I run it in the Command Prompt (the black DOS window) it fails as expected and shows me the detailed error message saying why it failed. However, when this script is run inside the package, the only error message I get is **The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".** I do not get the same detailed error message as I did when it failed in the Command Prompt.

The example .bat script I am using simply has this in it. **mkdir C:\test**

So, if C:\test folder already exists, it fails. My real script is something else which works fine in Command Prompt, but fails in SSIS, which I why I am trying to see the detailed error message.

So, that is the background, and I was told by someone that the way to capture the detailed error is to use StandardErrorVariable option in the Execute Process task as follows.

First, here is what the control flow looks like.

[image]

As you can see, I have an Execute Process task called "Run Bat File". It is configured as follows. C:\temp\Test.bat is the bat file that will fail. And I've added a variable called "Error" to the StandardErrorVariable option.

[image]

Next, I added a Script task and added the variable "Error" for ReadOnlyVaribles.

[image]

And finally, for the script, I added the following. I don't know much about this part. I am basically following something someone else showed me. Everything else besides what I circles is just the template that SSIS gives you when you open up a new Script window.

[image]

When I deploy this to the SSIS catalog and run it, as expected, the package fails, but I do not get the desired result. I still get the vague **The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0"** error coming from the Execute Process task.

Plus I get an error coming from the Script task that says, **The element cannot be found in a collection. This error happens when you try to retrieve an element from a collection on a container during execution of the package and the element is not there.**

***What did I do wrong in the Script task?***

***EDIT #1:*** I am adding a screen shot of the variables window in response to the comment that the error on the Script task might be related to the variable scope.

Here is what the variables window looks like.

[image]

When I click on the circled icon (called Move Variable), I see this. I think this means the variable is scoped at the package level (?)

[image]

***EDIT #2:*** Fixed the silly spelling mistake and now the package runs and I see the error from the test .bat file being logged. But when I run this package with the real script I need to run, I get the following log information.

**Run Bat File:Error: In Executing "c:\program files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" "/script=\dcmfs01\Datafile05\BBG_DataLicense\BBG_Instruments\script\Delete.txt /parameter BBG_BVOL_DAILY.dat.20220724xx" at "", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".
Script Task:Error:**

Notice that the Script task did get fired but it looks like the "error" variable didn't see any error messages. I am inferring this because there is nothing after the "Script Task:Error:" part in the above.

So on a hunch, I changed the Execute Process task to look like this. I moved the error variable to StandardOutputVariable.

[image]

When I run the package with this change, I see the expected error being logged, which now says...

**Run Bat File:Error: In Executing "c:\program files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" "/script=\dcmfs01\Datafile05\BBG_DataLicense\BBG_Instruments\script\Delete.txt /parameter BBG_BVOL_DAILY.dat.20220724xx" at "", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".
Script Task:Error: Searching for host...
Connecting to host...
Authenticating...
Using username "xxxxxxxxx".
Authenticating with pre-entered password.
Authenticated.
Starting the session...
Session started.
Active session: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTSyA.jpg) xxxxxx@sftp.xxxxxxxx.com / Can't get attributes of file 'BBG_BVOL_DAILY.dat.20220724xx'.
No such file or directory.
Error code: 2
Error message from server: No such file**

So... bottom line, I got it to show me the error message but apparently this is coming from the standard output.

**3 questions that come from this.

1. Why is it coming from the standard output if the Execute Process task failed?
2. Why does it say "The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0"" but the Scrip task indicates Error code 2? Not sure if this means anything significant to what I am trying to do, which is to make sure I capture all errors.
3. What if there is a different kind of failure where the message comes from standard error? Do I need to configure another Script task with another variable assigned to StandardErrorVariable to capture that scenario?**

Answer (score 0):

The variable is referenced incorrectly in the script - remove the "s" from User::Error**s**.
It should be:
`Dts.Variables["User::Error"].Value.ToString()`